# Is it possible to host pbix and rdl files on the same report server instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssrs, powerbi

Just upgraded an existing instance of SQL Server 2014 to 2016. That instance has an instance of Reporting Services installed. My end goal is to connect Power BI Desktop (March 2018) to my existing report server. I've downloaded and installed Power BI Report Server. Worked through the reporting services configuration manager.

In Power BI Desktop, I try to pass my existing url to the Power BI Report Server Selection pane. The url that i'm passing is pulled straight from the config manager and I can connect to it using IE. Current error reads: "We couldn't find a Power BI Report Server at this address"

I've restarted the the service on my windows box, still no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible and I am using it on my organization.

Just one tip: to deploy reports, we need to provide the Report Server URL (by default /reportserver) but on Power BI, we need to provide the report manager URL (default /reports).

Comment: Just so that that I understand correctly. You're saying that 2 urls are used to deploy each file type.

1. Mycompany/reportserver --> rdl
2. Mycompany/reports --> pbix

but both those urls point to the same site..

Comment: Yes. To deploy reports (SSRS) you point to http://myserver/reportserver. On Power BI, it is http://myserver/reports. You can also upload your .pbix file on the report manager. Could you give more details about your URLs?

Comment: Yes I think I need to create the second url. Currently they are both using the same url. myserver/reports when I went through the power bi report server install there was a warning indicating that the url had already been reserved. I didn't think much of it as everything had succeeded up to that point.

Comment: Are you able to apply scheduled refreshes using power bi desktop?

Comment: Yes, sure. And you can update it much more frequently than using the cloud version

Comment: Sorry the many questions! A gateway isn't required to implement the schedule refresh right? 

When I attempt to create the refresh I get an error stating that it can't find the file. But I've uploaded the file specifically to where it should be.

Comment: You don't need the gateway to refresh reports on Power BI Report Server. Just mind that if you are pointing you file to C:\temp, for example, after deploy the server will look on C:\temp of the server, now from your PC.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get Power BI Desktop to find my ReportServer, I had to grant OS level permissions to the user account opening Power BI Desktop.

This doesn't solve hosting pbix and rdl's on the same URL. Also, a gateway has to be set up in order to get scheduled refreshes working.